# VB how to define windows 1252 encoding for filewriter with umlauts?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ssis

I am writing a text file (that is used for texts on a webpage) and can not get the umlauts to show correctly. I suspect that I need to write the text in win1252 encoding, but do not know how to define it in vb

Here is the encoding definition

```
info = New UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(item)
```

What I tried, but It does not work

```
info = New Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(item)
```

Comment: Normally everything would work if you keep everything as UTF-8. How are you putting the contents of the text file onto the web page? What are the umlauted characters showing as?

Comment: when you say it doesn't work what do you mean? It doesn't encode they way you want it too? It gives you an error?  If so please include it.  Also what is the rest of your code if that is the case.  I use pretty much the same syntax for 1252 which is the encoding for SQL-server's default collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.  Are you perhaps trying to translate one codec to another? Such as are you wanting to go from 1252 to UFT16?